# Error on Samsung S3 with external memory card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, system-error, external-sd

My external 64GB ScanDisk Ultra is being causing me problems with my Samsung Galaxy S3. It works good for a small period of time, and then it crashes, it just stops working. It mostly holds music.

Suddenly it appears that there is not an external card, so I have to take out the card and reboot the phone, and then the card will work for another couple of days.

The phone is rooted, it works amazing, but Ive being having that problem. Is there anything I can do?